# Not able to Delete file using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a question related to NSIS.
I have an installer created by NSIS in ("c:/Installer/**Installer.exe**" folder).
When I run the installer it creates a log file("c:/Installer/**installlog.txt**") in the installation folder. After I successfully run Installer.exe I want only the installlog.txt to be deleted from "c:/Installer" .

I have the following function

```
Function .onInstSuccess
    call cleanUp
    ifSilent 0 +2
             ${LogText} "INFO :: Application has been installed"
             CopyFiles "$EXEDIR\${INSTALL_LOG}" "$Dir\LogFiles\"
             IfFileExists "$Dir\LogFiles\{INSTALL_LOG}" DoNothing CopyAgain
             CopyAgain:
                CopyFiles "$DIR\${INSTALL_LOG}" "$Dir\LogFiles\"
                Delete "$DIR\${INSTALL_LOG}"
                goto DoNothing
             DoNothing:           
             SetOutPath $EXEDIR     
             Delete "$EXEDIR\*.log" ;....................**but the file does not get deleted**
FunctionEnd
```

can some one please tell me how can I make this work.
I need to fix this as soon as possible, help on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: You want to delete `$DIR\${INSTALL_LOG}`? What do you have instead in the detail log when the file should have been deleted, an error message?

Comment: If the file is being used it can't be deleted, you should either close it or use /REBOOTOK to indicate the delete instruction to delete it on reboot

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [these](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Logging%3a_Simple_Text_File_Logging_Functions_and_Macros) logging macros. You should call `${LogSetOff}` after the last call to `${LogText}` so the file handle is closed, you should then be able to delete the file.

Also, using `Delete "$EXEDIR\*.log"` is not a good idea, you already know the filename...